# what is the difference between using ext to extend a list and using a plus operator to add to a list?

Tags: list

what is the difference between using ext to extend a list and using a plus operator to add to a list?

Im learning lists and the question was:Use the + operator to paste the list ["poolhouse", 24.5] to the end of the areas list. Store the resulting list as areas_1.
Further extend areas_1 by adding data on your garage. Add the string "garage" and float 15.45. Name the resulting list areas_2.

```
# Create the areas list (updated version)

  areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0, "chill zone", 20.0,
     "bedroom", 10.75, "bathroom", 10.50]

# Add poolhouse data to areas, new list is areas_1

  areas_1 = areas + ["poolhouse", 24.5]

# Add garage data to areas_1, new list is areas_2

  areas_2 = areas_1 + ["garage", 15.45]
```

the above is correct answer but I put areas [:-9] to add after bathroom, then area_ext to add poolhouse, but the answer says just use + operator. whats the difference I dont get it

i added areas_ext = areas + ['poolhouse'] but it was wrong

Comment: This really requires a language tag